# Downloading and exporting a zip file from url using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, download, zip

I have looked over the responses to previous zip downloading questions and I keep running into problems. I used BeatifulSoup to identify a particular zip file I want to download using the following code:

```
state_fips = '06'
county_fips = '037'
url = 'https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020/ROADS/'
url_get = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'html.parser')

# get state and county fips
st_cnty_string = f'tl_2020_{state_fips}{county_fips}'
```

I then try to read and write the data to a file but I keep getting errors or files that have 0 bytes. I am not sure where the problem/s is/are:

```
link = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(st_cnty_string)})
data = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, link.get('href'))
open('test.zip', 'wb').write(data)
```

I get the following error for this attempt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `urllib.open()`?  What version of python are you using?  Should that be `urllib.request.urlopen()`?  If it's `urlopen()`, then that doesn't actually return a string.  It returns a [`HTTPResponse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) object.

Comment: Could you include the errors you are receiving. Errors tell a lot of information about what is going wrong

Comment: And what code changes cause/stop certain errors. That would be good to include too

Comment: Sorry. I've tried a few things and have gotten different errors. I will add a bit more detail.

Comment: That's not how [`urllib.request.urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) works.  If you want to save the file, then couldn't you just do `urllib.request.urlretrieve(link.get('href'), 'test.zip')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that BeautifulSoup returns relative links. But you need a complete url to download the zipfile.

Try this:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(st_cnty_string)}):
    link_abs = f'{url}/{link.get("href")}'
    with open('test.zip', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(link_abs).content)
```

Comment: Thank you -- that was the issue! I'll update the title so people can find this easier if they run into same problem.